# LDAP (Windows) login on Debian9

Tags: debian, samba, ldap, winbind

I've configured my Debian9 with Kerberus5, Samba and Winbind to login on a windows domain, all the configuration is already set and I've already tested it (it works!), but when I try to realize my login as a domain user, I cannot connect on the machine. I've tried these ways to login:

```
IMPD\murilo.melo
IMPD.LOCAL\murilo.melo
murilo.melo
murilo.melo@IMPD
murilo.melo@IMPD.LOCAL
```

My relevant confs are:

nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         compat winbind 
group:          compat winbind
```

krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = IMPD.LOCAL
[realms]
IMPD.LOCAL = {
    kdc = srvdc01.impd.local 
    default_domain = impd.local 
    admin_server = srvdc01.impd.local
}
[domain_realm]
    .impd.local = IMPD.LOCAL
    impd.local = IMPD.LOCAL
[login]
krb4_convert = true
krb4_get_tickets = false
```

ntp.conf

```
#Controlador de domínio
server 10.100.0.1
restrict 10.100.0.1
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1   debian.impd.local   debsede localhost
127.0.1.1   debian

10.100.0.1 srvdc01.impd.local srvdc01
```

common-session

```
session required    pam_unix.so 
session required    pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
session optional    pam_winbind.so
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
 workgroup = IMPD.LOCAL 
 server string = DEBSEDE01
 netbios name = DEBSEDE
 realm = IMPD.LOCAL
 security = ads 

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = IMPD
```

resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search IMPD.LOCAL
nameserver 10.100.0.1
nameserver 10.100.0.2
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

My problem is just the logon action in my domain, my Debian says:

> "Sorry, this isn't working. Please try again"

*I've already tried to use another users, like the user I used to login on ldap with `net ads join`

Login Report (with auditd)

```
============================================
# date time auid host term exe success event
============================================
1. 25-06-2019 11:53:42 murilo.melo ? ? /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-session-worker no 10
2. 25-06-2019 11:53:56 IMPD\murilo.melo ? ? /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-session-worker no 12
3. 25-06-2019 11:54:10 IMPD.LOCAL\murilo.melo ? ? /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-session-worker no 14
4. 25-06-2019 11:54:24 murilo.melo ? ? /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-session-worker no 16
5. 25-06-2019 11:54:36 murilo.melo@IMPD ? ? /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-session-worker no 18
```

Comment: do you see any useful information in your auth log?

Comment: I've edited my question :D

Comment: can you please try, as root, `su - murilo.melo@IMPD.LOCAL`?

Comment: I get "No pass to user murilo.melo@IMPD.LOCAL"

Comment: @TimKennedy I've tried su - [user] in some other ways, but all of them result the same error :/